# App Engine Java Unit Test Environment Setup

Tags: java, unit-testing, google-app-engine

we use the appengine-web.xml file to store global config data  as system properties (like the location of various development servers we need to communicate with). These properties are not available when running unit test with the LocalServiceTestHelper class. There seem to be methods to set the desired system properties during setUp of each unit test (cf. e.g. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/development/testing/LocalServiceTestHelper.html#setEnvAttributes(java.util.Map)) but so far we have failed to implement this.

It would be great if somebody could provide a simple example of how to set a system property in a app engine unit test?

**EDIT: here is a minimal example that demonstrates what I am trying to do**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper;

public class MyTest {
    private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());
@Before
public void setUp() {
    Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    values.put("de.foo.bar", "baz");
    helper.setEnvAttributes(values);
    helper.setUp();
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    helper.tearDown();
}

@Test
public void foo() {
    System.out.println("my env variable: " + System.getenv("de.foo.bar"));
}
```

}

This prints out "my env variable: null"

Comment: what do you using for project environment? maven? IDE? other?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you have failed to implement this?  What did you try, and what happened?

Comment: @splix: I use Eclipse 3.7 with a standard App Engine setup

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/development/testing/LocalServiceTestHelper#setEnvAttributes%28java.util.Map%29), I think the method `setEnvAttributes()` does something different than you expect. The environment attributes you're setting are available using [`Environment.getAttributes()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/apphosting/api/ApiProxy.Environment#getAttributes%28%29) not `System.getenv()`